# Passing the function as an if parameter

Tags: javascript, function

I was kinda thinking about this and I don't quite get it. Here is the example:

```
function greet() {
    console.log('Hello')
}

if(greet()){
    console.log('Hi')
}
```

Is the greet function just simply getting called (because the result is just hello)? And what happens to the console.log('Hi') and why doesn't it get called?

Comment: The greet function is called and returns `undefined`, which means the if statement won't be true and the "Hi" won't be logged.

Comment: `greet` doesn't *return* anything, so it *implicitly* returns `undefined`, which is a "falsey" value (when coerced to a boolean, it's false). Since it's falsey, the code inside the if statement never runs (the condition in the if statement must evaluate to a truthy value).

Comment: in `if(greet())` you are calling the function, so it gets executed. since your function does return `undefined`, it does not satisfy the condition, so `console.log('Hi')` does not get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Unline `printf` in C, `console.log` of javascript does not return anything after pringing to console.
So the `if` condition becomes falsy.